# How to get a real path of a Python file in Project Directory

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, automation, python-unittest

I am using an Automation project with following structure

```
C:\Project_Name\Scripts
```

Under script folder, I have my python automation modules, libraries and other required data folders.

But I want this project not only restricted to C: drive. I should seamlessly able to execute by scripts from any drive, any parent directory of "Project_Name" folder.

I have tried the following. But it is always not true if I try to trigger my test from jenkins.

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a way to get the real path of the file no matter where the project directory been placed.

```
import os
os.path.join((os.path.realpath(__file__)).split("<Base Directory Name>")[0], "<relative path till the file>")
```

this worked as well,  with simple path.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this tree:

```
Project
 |
 |--Scripts
 |   |
 |   |--__init__.py
 |   |--use_text.py
 |   |--text.txt
 |
 |--run_me.py
```

and imagine we have to get text.txt path in use_text.py
Step 1. in `run_me.py` get the path of project directory, and save it as a environ using os. (example:)

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
path = Path(__file__).parent # replace it with your preferred library's version
os.environ['PROJECT_BASE_DIR'] = str(path)

from Scripts.use_text import use
use()
```

now in `use_text.py`

```
import os
text_path = 'Scripts/text.txt'
project_path = os.getenv('PROJECT_BASE_DIR')
text_real_path = os.path.join(project_path, text_path)

def use():
   # do whatever you want with text_real_path
```

Comment: import os
from pathlib import Path
os.environ['PROJECT_BASE_DIR'] = str(Path(__file__).parent)
project_path = os.getenv('PROJECT_BASE_DIR').split('scripts')[0] this is a good help..Thanks